# Erratic behavior of train_test_split() in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Python 3.5 (anaconda install)
SciKit 0.17.1

I just can't understand why `train_test_split()` has been giving me what I consider unreliable splits of a list of training cases.

Here's an example.
My list `trnImgPaths` has 3 classes, each one with 67 images (total 201 images):

```
['/Caltech101/ferry/image_0001.jpg',
   ... thru ...
 '/Caltech101/ferry/image_0067.jpg',
 '/Caltech101/laptop/image_0001.jpg',
   ... thru ...
 '/Caltech101/laptop/image_0067.jpg',
 '/Caltech101/airplane/image_0001.jpg',
   ... thru ...
 '/Caltech101/airplane/image_0067.jpg']
```

My list of targets `trnImgTargets` perfectly matches this both in length and also the classes themselves align perfectly with `trnImgPaths`.

```
In[148]: len(trnImgPaths)
Out[148]: 201
In[149]: len(trnImgTargets)
Out[149]: 201
```

If I run:

```
[trnImgs, testImgs, trnTargets, testTargets] = \
    train_test_split(trnImgPaths, trnImgTargets, test_size=141, train_size=60, random_state=42)
```

or

```
[trnImgs, testImgs, trnTargets, testTargets] = \
    train_test_split(trnImgPaths, trnImgTargets, test_size=0.7, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

or

```
[trnImgs, testImgs, trnTargets, testTargets] = \
    train_test_split(trnImgPaths, trnImgTargets, test_size=0.7, train_size=0.3)
```

Although I end up getting:

```
In[150]: len(trnImgs)
Out[150]: 60
In[151]: len(testImgs)
Out[151]: 141
In[152]: len(trnTargets)
Out[152]: 60
In[153]: len(testTargets)
Out[153]: 141
```

I never get a perfect split of 20 - 20 - 20 for the training set. I can tell because both by manual checking and doing a sanity check by confusion matrix.
Here are the results for each experiment above, respectively:

```
[[19  0  0]
 [ 0 21  0]
 [ 0  0 20]]

[[19  0  0]
 [ 0 21  0]
 [ 0  0 20]]

[[16  0  0]
 [ 0 22  0]
 [ 0  0 22]]
```

I expected the split to be perfectly balanced. Any thoughts why this is happening?

It even appears it may be misclassifying a few cases a priori, because there will never be n=22 training cases for a given class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: this is expected behaviour.

Random splitting does not guarantee "balanced" splits. This is what **stratified** splitting is for (also [implemented in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)).

Comment: interesting... it's too bad I didn't find this "feature" in the docs, nor what kind of tolerance they implemented for the unequal selection of cases when random splitting -- train_test_split also has a stratified argument -- could that be used to lock in the n of cases?

Comment: yes, you can also pass a specific values to stratify argument. For random splitting there is no "tolerance" - this is literaly random split, whatever is generated by random numbers generator - is used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @lejlot comments, the way I managed to lock in the number of cases was using a new feature for [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) on SKLearn 0.17. There is now an argument called **stratify**, which I'm using as follow (this will force the split to follow the number of labels in your label list):

```
[trnImgs, testImgs, trnTargets, testTargets] = \
    train_test_split(trnImgPaths, trnImgTargets, test_size=0.7,
                     train_size=0.3, stratify=trnImgTargets)
```

Now, every time I run the script I get:

```
[[20  0  0]
 [ 0 20  0]
 [ 0  0 20]]
```